# Underlined AttributedString produces errors in Swift 4

Tags: swift, xcode, nsattributedstring, swift4

I have discovered that my App crashes whenever I add an attribute that underlines the text in an `NSAttributedString`. The documentation of `NSAttributedStringKey.underlineStyle` clearly states that the value should be a constant from `NSUnderlineStyle`. By simply putting the following code in a playground you instantly see an error.

```
import UIKit

let underlinedAttributes: [NSAttributedStringKey: Any] = [
    NSAttributedStringKey.underlineStyle : NSUnderlineStyle.styleSingle
]

let attributedString = NSAttributedString(string: "Test", attributes: underlinedAttributes)
```

Error: [_SwiftValue encodeWithEncoder:] unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x6040000451...

Is this a bug or is there a solution?

Comment: `NSUnderlineStyle.styleSingle.rawValue` instead of `NSUnderlineStyle.styleSingle`.

Comment: It works, but that is just really ugly syntax. Well well.. Thanks for the help :) I just assumed that they had made the syntax prettier.

Comment: Do you know if this applies generally for all values in the attributes dictionaries?

Comment: You only need to apply `.rawValue` if the attribute value type is an enum.

Comment: That is what I meant. So the `.rawValue` is needed to get an NSNumber for the value then I guess?